# Cosmos DB OFFSET LIMIT (NoSQL query) RU cost

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In the official CosmosDB documentation, we can find information about the inefficient OFFSET LIMIT clause.

"The RU charge of a query with OFFSET LIMIT increases as the number of terms being offset increases. For queries that have multiple pages of results, we typically recommend using continuation tokens."

[Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z7GX.png)

Here is link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/offset-limit#remarks

Not sure if this Cosmos DB documentation is out of date, or just incorrect.

But I have evidence that using OFFSET LIMIT does not load each skipped item & the RU cost is negligible.

Below are screenshots to prove the results.

[OFFSET 0, LIMIT 10: 3.22 RUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLl8.png)

[OFFSET 500, LIMIT 10: 3.12 RUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7RD2.png)

[OFFSET 5,000, LIMIT 10: 3.35 RUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uzII.png)

[OFFSET 160,000, LIMIT 10: 3.29 RUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAozO.png)

If anyone can clarify this, please share your thoughts.

I tried to find more information about pagination, and in all the sources I found, the continuation token is the most preferable way to implement pagination in CosmosDB. I want to understend why my results contradict the documentation.

Comment: Unsure. But seems to be a result of you filtering on the partition key. It can probably leverage the index because you stay within the same partition and won't need to zip results together of multiple partitions and thus iterate over all documents. It's weird that it's not described in the documentation since it's not unusual to query over a specific partition.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation looks out of date.

The passages you highlighted ...

> The RU charge of a query with `OFFSET LIMIT` will increase as the number of terms being offset increases ... On the backend, `OFFSET LIMIT` still loads each document, including those that are skipped

... were [added in Jan 2020](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/44ff8cd8bc2c6e88b7301f28824d223ffa6244c4)

This [Blog from June 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-a-new-system-function-and-optimized-query-operators/#offset-limit-optimizations) announces

> **OFFSET LIMIT optimizations**
>
> The query engine will now be able to avoid
> document loading time and parsing time for documents outside of the
> offset range

Comment: I don't think the blog post describes this behavior. It only seems to explain how there's a "slight" optimization (specifically for execution time) when using OFFSET with a case where RU charge linearly increases with the OFFSET count (indicated by the high RU charge). It also doesn't mention the partition key which seems vital for the observations by the OP, because not filtering on the partition key results in the same behavior that's described in the documentation.

Comment: @NotFound - The OP here is only selecting 10 documents and offsetting 160,000 - I would expect not having to load 160K unnecessary documents and simply counting the index entries is more than "slight" benefit. And yeah not clear if/how this would work cross partition. The docs need to be updated

Comment: but the example from the blog only offsets 1000 documents and the optimizations only results in <10% RU gains. While it might avoid loading time it still clearly iterates over all documents (whether actual documents or index) as indicated by the 100x higher RU charge compared to that of OP. The optimization from the post is not the reason why the OP's query performs so well.

Comment: The example in the Blog is not going to be able to be done with a simple index scan of a single path. It has an inequality on `Price ` and `ORDER BY` on `FirstAvailable` - so not comparable to this query. Certainly I would be hoping for much better RU savings than stated there if all it has to do is count index entries from a single path and then retrieve 10 documents. And can save having to do document lookups for the 160K skipped documents

Comment: If the optimization won't work because of the expressions then why would they use it as example? I tried the blog post query on a similar database (1.8m). Using a range filter, order by, and similar offset I got ~200 RU charge. Increasing the offset results in a (almost) linear increase in RU's used. Thus it's clear that it's iterating over the documents, which matches the OP's documentation reference and is **not** the case with his query. This optimization is not the cause of the OP's low RU charge as there's no linear increase in RU charge at all.